# bad interpreter: No such file or directory, something to do with classpath?

Tags: java, bash, shell

I [downloaded](ftp://ftp.cis.upenn.edu/pub/adwait/jmx/jmx.tar.gz) MxTerminator and followed [these instructions](http://web.mit.edu/course/6/6.863/tools/jmx/MXTERMINATOR.html). I unzipped it into a directory called jmx. Then I did step 1, Edit your CLASSPATH variable to include file mxpost.jar. So I used this command:

`export CLASSPATH=/usr/home/daniel/jmx/mxpost.jar`

Then I did step 2:

`mxterminator jmx< engcorpus.txt`

but it says:

`bash: ./mxpost: /bin/ksh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

I think something is wrong with my classpath?

I am using Linux Mint 14 (same as Ubuntu)

But the file exists! And I tried other answers, but they didn't work for me.

Comment: Do you really have ksh installed and at `/bin/ksh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, nothing to do with your classpath. `mxpost` is a `ksh` script, and it looks like you don't have `ksh` installed.

Comment: Or, if it is installed, it is not in `/bin/ksh` but somewhere else (`/usr/bin/ksh`, `/usr/local/bin/ksh`, ...).

Comment: How do I edit my classpath so it doesn't override everything else (like svn)?

Comment: @user1925847 what? classpath doesn't have any effect on svn.